# I can't install the program on any computer. "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-installer

I made a program using .NET 4, Visual Studio 15.7 and build the .msi installer. The installer is supposed to run a .bat file during the installation and it perfectly works on my own pc, but when I try to install it on another pc an error pops up:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

I executed it as administrator, using the administrator account and even using a simple "echo" on the scrip to see if the commands were the problem but the installation fails every time unless I remove the .bat execution from the installer.

The scrip can be manually executed after the installation (without the .bat execution been part of the installation), so the commands in the file are not the problem.

Do I need to grant any kind of permission to the .bat file before I build the installer or something like that? I really don't know why isn't working

This is my .bat file content

```
@echo off
echo Installing
pause
```

And this is how I set the custom action to execute a .bat:

[image: .bat file execution configuration]

Comment: Please show us your .bat file and how the custom action is configured.

Comment: Make sure the Custom Action is scheduled to run AFTER the InstallFiles standard action and before InstallFinalize. And make sure it is set to run as Deferred in a system context (and not immediate).

Comment: @Captain_Planet How can I schedule it to run that way and where do I set it as Deferred?

Comment: Well, firstly I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve?  Your bat file has a 'pause' and so probably doesn't even return back to the custom action?  What are you trying to do exactly?